# How to omit characters from an inputted number in C?

Tags: c, output, primes

I'm new to C and have been playing about and having created a basic input output program for integers (See below) I was wondering how I would go about making my program omit characters from an inputted number and then print the number without said omitted characters so for example if I wanted it to omit non-primes 1234567 entered would print 2357. Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int number;

// printf() dislpays the formatted output 
printf("Enter an integer: ");  

// scanf() reads the formatted input and stores them
scanf("%d", &number);  

// printf() displays the formatted output
printf("You entered: %d", number);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The obvious way is to examine the input digit by digit (could be more clever ways). So can you think of how to do that?

Comment: you can read the number into array, and then its really easy to manage the digits, or use modulus `%` to check digit by digit